# unable to open printf, unable to read file

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, permission-denied, vscode-debugger

i am trying to debug a ".c" file in vs code in my ubuntu machine, but i am having this issue.

```
 Unable to open 'printf.c': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/stdio-common/printf.c)).
```

after i say "Create File" it gives this error

```
Unable to write file (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/build')
```

i am trying to debug a simple "hello world" code.
also in any function like, malloc etc. it gives the same error outline.

what might be the problem and the solution?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `printf` is part of the standard library. Why do you want to debug *inside* of it?

Comment: when i was in windows or before a few days in my ubuntu machine, "step into" was working perfectly fine with anything.

Comment: The IDE is just telling you that you don't have the source files for the library, so it cannot show it to you. You can still look at the assembly and debug in that, but there really is no point in stepping inside standard library functions anyway, in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i think i got it but i have a follow-up just for my curiosity. what is the difference on windows? it does step into but it acts like step over on windows rather than giving an error message.

Comment: That will be up to how exactly the debugger behaves. Did you use Visual Studio on Windows? I don't really know much about working with it.

Comment: i am using gcc with visual studio code

Comment: Then I guess you don't have debug symbols for the standard library on Windows, but that you do on Ubuntu. The debug symbols contain e.g. the source path, etc. Whether or not they are shipped with the library depends on the OS/distribution. For example in Ubuntu there are two `libc` packages, the normal one and the `-dbg` one which contains the debug symbols (but apparently not the source files as explained in the linked duplicate).